# Setting a breakpoint on Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() seems to be modifying the last error set?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, setupapi

I am using C# with .NET 4.6 in VS2019 on Win10 x64 1809.

When using P/Invoke, setting a breakpoint on a "Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()" line seems to be modifying the last-set Win32 error code.

For example:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void SetLastError(
            uint dwErrCode
            );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int startErr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            SetLastError(500);
            int endError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on "return", repeated runs show endError as 500.

However, if I set the breakpoint on "int endError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();", repeated runs show endError as 0.

---

It appears that setting a breakpoint on any "Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()" line will produce unexpected results, as in another area whilst P/Invoking SetupEnumInfSections() I expected 259 (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS), but upon setting a breakpoint, receive 1008 instead.

---

- Am I missing something that is causing this behavior in my projects? (I've tried different projects, both personal and third-party from CodeProject and GitHub, and continue to experience this behavior)
- Is this an error in Visual Studio (should I report this?)
- Is this expected? (See below)

---

I was aware that calling Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() needs to be called immediately following the API call in question (presuming that the API call does indeed set the last error, and for P/Invoke calls, includes "SetLastError = true" in it's decorator), because any additional call could modify the last error's value.

However, I didn't find any other sort of warning with respect to debugging, setting a breakpoint on a Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), etc.

Is this a "gotcha" that developers writing P/Invoke with VS should be aware of, similar to following API calls immediately with GetLastError() and setting the decorator ("SetLastError = true")? It might be a "gotcha", but if so, it isn't immediately apparent to me because I expect each process to have it's own last error, including VS (and/or the debugger), but maybe it's tied to the underlying application in some way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @KenWhite Respectfully, I've read the documentation, and I understand your point, but I feel like you didn't read (or comprehend) my question. In my example, I literally SetLastError() and then immediately call GetLastError(), with the only change being I set a breakpoint in the VS debugger—setting a breakpoint in the VS debugger is modifying my application's process's last error?

Comment: Yep. I misunderstood your question. Comment deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Since you're here and obviously have experience on this topic as well, can you tell me if I've overlooked something else obvious? When I narrowed it down to the example above, I feel like it's a bug—but this happens in VS2017, too. If this is a bug, clearly it should've been reported already, and I would expect to find_something_ regarding it when performing a search.

Comment: _However, if I set the breakpoint on "int endError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();", repeated runs show endError as 0._ Am I being thick or is `endError` not set until this line actually executes.  BTW, `GetLastError()` is per-thread, not per-process.  You can view it in the debugger via pseudo-variable `ERR` (or, better perhaps, `ERR,hr`).

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on return and run, endError should show 500 in Auto/Locals. If you then add another breakpoint on GetLastWin32Error(), run to GetLastWin32Error() and then continue, I see endError as 0 (instead of 500.)

Comment: if exist such effect, here faster of all due how breakpoint for managed code is implemented. can for test instead set breakpoint in debugger, call say `DebugBreak` - are this also change `GetLastWin32Error` return value ?

Comment: Been writing interop for 20 years. Yes, last error can be painful. For what it's worth my rules are: 1) Make sure to SetLastError=true only on functions that support it, 2) Never use SetLastError for my own functions (use HRESULTs) 3) set a variable to Marshal.GetLastError right after a call, and 4) never use anything but that value, in code or debugger

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the advice—I think these are good lessons anyone writing P/Invoke code can benefit from. I'm even guilty of adding "SetLastError = true" as a decorator in my example above (although admittedly I just threw that project together to test the theory.) Your points for #3 and #4 are the most helpful with respect to this issue; are you (or can you) confirm this has always been the behavior of the VS debugger when setting a breakpoint on a Marshal.GetLastError() line?

Comment: One non-obvious issue with the "last error" state is that it is a thread-local variable.  Necessarily so, a winapi error in one thread should not corrupt the error state of another.  The managed debugger has two basic ways to evaluate watch expressions, it can run the code on the same thread that is currently active or it can use a dedicated debugging thread that the CLR automatically starts.  It uses the latter if it deems the current thread in a state that is not safe to run any code.  Which one it uses is quite unpredictable and not easy to see.  Other than with this code ;)

Comment: @HansPassant That's really enlightening, and explains the behavior—thanks. You indicated it's unpredictable; is there any way to specify to Visual Studio which behavior you'd prefer (e.g. "always spawn a dedicated debugging thread"?)

Comment: You can safely assume I would have mentioned that if it were possible.

Comment: @HansPassant If you'd like to submit your comment as an answer, I'll select it as the answer—the debugger is unpredictable, and I've opened a ticket with the Visual Studio team to (at the very least notify) them of this behavior.